# My minecraft world spawn keeps setting underground?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a Java server set up through Aternos to play with friends, spawn used to be in an empty field area in the middle of the map and I have recently built a building near by to move spawn to. However, when I tried to set spawn there and test it, it tps me and others to the large cavern 70 blocks underneath the spawn building. I have tried the /setworldspawn with nothing added and with my exact coords, and I have tried /gamerule spawnradius 2 but nothing is working, I will try any and all suggestions people have, thank you!

Comment: It would be useful if you'd include which command you've used.

Comment: ... and what plugins (if any)

Answer (score 1):

You likely have something like [EssentialsEX](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/essentialsx.9089/), [Nucleus](https://v2.nucleuspowered.org/) or [Essentials](https://hub.spigotmc.org/jenkins/job/Spigot-Essentials/) overriding default Vanilla spawning behaviour.

Try `/setworldspawn` (Essentials), `/minecraft:setworldspawn` (Vanilla), or `/setspawn` (Essentials, also).

It is possible you have `/spawnpoint` yourself. In that case, you may need to use `/spawnpoint @a clear` (older versions of Minecraft/Essentials) or `/clearspawnpoint`/`/minecraft:clearspawnpoint` (Minecraft).